# Get Week Number on Different First Month of Year and Different First Day Of Week

Tags: c#

How to get week number in a custom starting month of the year and custom starting day of week? I have made a code based on this where I made first of october as the first month of year, and saturday as the first day of the week.

```
public static int GetLWNumber(DateTime date)
    {
        // Set the starting day of the week to Saturday
        DayOfWeek startingDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;

        // Calculate the start date of the logweek period
        DateTime logweekStart;
        if (date.Month >= 10) // October to December of the same year
        {
            logweekStart = new DateTime(date.Year, 10, 1);
        }
        else // January to September of the previous year
        {
            logweekStart = new DateTime(date.Year - 1, 10, 1);
        }

        // Calculate the days between the date and the logweek start date
        int daysSinceLogweekStart = (date.Date - logweekStart).Days;

        // Adjust the days to ensure the week starts on Saturday
        int adjustedDays = daysSinceLogweekStart + (7 - (int)logweekStart.DayOfWeek + (int)startingDayOfWeek) % 7;

        // Calculate the logweek number by dividing the adjusted days by 7
        int logweekNumber = adjustedDays / 7;

        return logweekNumber;
    }
```

But in this program, I get an error where sometimes I give a date but it still take the monday as the starting day of the week.

Comment: Read your post carefully and ponder whether you would know a)what the problem is or b) how to solve it based on the jumble of words posted if that was all you were given.

Comment: It seems quite clear to me. Why was this closed?

Comment: Please re-open.

Comment: Please update your post with what you've tried so far. It sounds like you've already figured out how to get week number from a "normal" year, correct? If so, it shouldn't be too hard to calculate from a different starting date. If not, try that first.

Comment: already updated. thanks!

Comment: `date.Month >= 10` is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: *"But in this program, I get an error where sometimes I give a date but it still take the monday as the starting day of the week"* What was the input data, expected output, and actual output? Step through the code and watch the values of the variables to track down where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that I think works for you:

```
int GetWeekNumber(DateTime input)
{
    var start = new DateTime(input.Year, 10, 1);
    start = start.AddDays((6 - (int)start.DayOfWeek) % 7);
    if (start > input)
    {
        start = new DateTime(input.Year - 1, 10, 1);
        start = start.AddDays((6 - (int)start.DayOfWeek) % 7);
    }
    return (int)(input.Date.Subtract(start).TotalDays / 7 + 1);
}
```

It produces 2 & 32 on the two sample dates you provided.